# On Windows, can't we have different versions of Ruby and Rails (or Gemsets) just by setting the PATH?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

As I remember, on Windows, all the gems get installed relative to `c:\ruby192`, so can we actually have different paths such as

```
c:\ruby187_rails238
c:\ruby187_rails301
c:\ruby192_rails301
c:\ruby192_try
```

and therefore have 2 Ruby installations and 2 gemsets for each of them, and create more gemsets as needed this way.  (just make sure to install a clean ruby into each new directory), and setting the PATH variable on Windows to change the Ruby and gemset to use.

Will that work flawlessly?

Answer (score 2):

That is actually not accurate. You can have one unique installation of each Ruby and manage it using [Pik](http://github.com/vertiginous/pik) (similar to RVM for Windows).

It's current state do not handle gemsets as RVM, but you can still play with `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME` environment variables to keep gems in isolation.

For example, I've set both variables to something different for each interpreter I have installed:

```
C:\Users\Luis>set GEM
GEM_HOME=C:\Users\Luis\.gem\ruby\x86-mingw32\1.8
GEM_PATH=C:\Users\Luis\.gem\ruby\x86-mingw32\1.8
```

You can do that setting one with the path you want `SET GEM_HOME=C:\My\Gem\Path` and then making the other clone it with `SET GEM_PATH=%GEM_HOME%`

Hope that helps.